# How do I group together two sets of dates by measuring the difference between each of them?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, timedelta

I am working on analyzing financial donations made to an NGO and how their social media engagement has impacted these donations. To this end, I wanted to group together donations made to the organizations with the dates on which social media posts were made. The dates of donations are stored in a dataframe under a 'Transaction Date' header, and the dates on which social media posts have been made have been scraped from Facebook and put in an array. The datatype for donation dates is `datetime64[ns]` and the datatype for social media post dates is `datetime.date`.

This is my code, roughly reproduced. Any help with regards to what changes I could make?

```
donation_timestamp = pd.DataFrame()
donation_timestamp['Dates'] = np.array(['2019-05-01', '2019-05-12', '2019-05-23'])
donation_timestamp['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(donation_timestamp['Dates'])

post_dates = pd.to_datetime(scraped_dates)
post_timestamps = []
for i in post_dates:
    time = dt.datetime.strptime(str(i), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
    post_timestamps.append(time)
post_timestamps = np.array(post_timestamps)

post_donations = dict.fromkeys(post_timestamps)
for i in post_timestamps:
    for j in donation_timestamp:
        if j-i < dt.timedelta(days=2):
            post_donations[i] = np.append(post_donations[i], j)
```

I created a new dictionary with the social media posts dates as keys, and tried to iterate over both these arrays. Wherever a donation has been made within two days of a social media post, I have tried to classify that donation date under the respective post date in my dictionary. I ran into problems with this loop logic, and my condition statement. For some reason, my `pd.timedelta` definition to check for the difference between two dates is not working - all iterations are satisfying the condition. Also I don't understand how to convert the datatypes so that I can seamlessly take the difference between the two dates.

Comment: It would be useful if you made the code example reproducible by providing a sample array of `scraped_dates`.

Comment: You might want to use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), but for specifics, we'd need to see a reproducible example including all inputs (i.e. `scraped_dates`) and desired output. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341), and [mre] in general. You can also minimize your code, for example, `donation_timestamp = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.to_datetime(['2019-05-01', ...]))` and `post_timestamps = pd.to_datetime(scraped_dates).dt.normalize()`. Just to be clear, `.strptime(str(i)` is totally redundant.

Answer (score -1):

Using pandas series to store the dates of the donations and media posts we can output a list of donations that are within two days after a media post in the following way:

```
dons = pd.Series(np.array(['2019-05-10', '2019-05-12', '2019-05-21']))
dons = pd.to_datetime(dons)
dons.sort_values(ascending=True, inplace=True)

scraped_data = ["2019-05-11 13:00:00", "2019-05-19 15:00:00"]
posts = pd.Series(scraped_data)
posts = pd.to_datetime(posts)
posts.sort_values(ascending=True, inplace=True)

p = 0
d = 0
promotion_donos = []
while p < len(posts) and d < len(dons):
    if 2 >= (dons[d] - posts[p]).days >= 0:
        promotion_donos.append(dons[d])
        d += 1  # go to next donation
    elif (dons[d] - posts[p]).days > 2:
        p += 1  # go to next media post
    else:  # post later than donation
        d += 1  # go to next donation

print(promotion_donos)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).